# MFC Progress Bar Issue And Filing Menu Generation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, progress-bar

```
void combination::OnButton2()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    m_progress.SetPos(0);
    m_progress.SetRange(0,100);

    combination a;
    a.make_combinations(0);
}

void combination::make_combinations(int lo_val)
{
    srand(time(0));
    m_progress.StepIt();
    ofstream fout("combination.txt",ios::app);
    ofstream fout2("time.txt",ios::app);

    for(int i=0; i<theApp.no_of_process; i++)
    {
        //m_progress.OffsetPos(100/4);
        //m_progress.SetStep(200);
        clock_t begin = clock();
        arr[lo_val] = i;
        if (lo_val == (theApp.no_of_tasks)-1)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<theApp.no_of_tasks; j++)
            {
                int number = arr[j];
                fout << Matrix[j][number];
            }
            fout<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            //Sleep(2);
            //make_combinations(lo_val+1);
            clock_t end = clock();
            theApp.combination_time[i][0] = (diffclock(end, begin))/1000;
            fout2 << theApp.combination_time[i][0] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

there is a dialog on mfc with a button behine that button am calling a recursive function. i placed a progress bar on the same dialog that should tell me the progress of recursion. but iam gettin an error on clicking the button. debug assertion failed. your program caused an assertion failure. i dnt know what is wrong with my code. please help!!

ISSUE NO 2:
Iam making this project on MFC! it includes brute force capability. It also has file handling in it!! am stuck at another point! i have a couple of files with file writing! my project has multiple files .txt format! on the main MFC board i want to add an option for browsing those written files . they should open in the format they are written! any help how it can be done?? just like a browsing menu! help??

Answer (score 0):

The assertion is probably because either the control does not exist on the dialog, or the variable `m_progress` has not been subclassed to the control.  Make sure you have a DDX_Control entry for `m_progress` in your `DoDataExchange` function.